# laravel query return Undefined

Tags: sql, laravel, where-clause

I do a search with 3 inputs and then input can be empty

i get variables from the front-end

```
$addressSearch = $request->json()->get('addressSearch');
$typeSearch    = $request->json()->get('typeSearch');
$statusSearch  = $request->json()->get('statusSearch');
```

I do this search use the function inside the query

```
$property = Property::where('id', '1')
                      ->Where(function($query)
                       {
                           $query->Where('type',typeSearch)
                                   ->orWhere('status',$statusSearch)
                                   ->orWhere('street','LIKE',"% $addressSearch}%");
                        })
                        ->get();
```

and I get this error:

> message: "Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\PropertyController::$typeSearch

the variable receives the value normally

Comment: typeSearch in line 4 should have $ sign, also check that which line error refer to

Comment: yes, have but keep sending me Undefined variable:

Answer (score 1):

You have type errors, and you're not passing any variables to the closure function, so they don't exist anyway:

```
$property = Property::where('id', '1')
                     ->where(function($query) use ($typeSearch, $statusSearch, $addressSearch)
                     {
                          $query->where('type',$typeSearch)
                                ->orWhere('status',$statusSearch)
                                ->orWhere('street','LIKE',"%{$addressSearch}%");
                     })->get();
```